# Eager Execution - InternalError: Could not find valid device for node name: "Sqrt"

Tags: python, tensorflow

With Eager Execution enabled the TensorFlow square-root function `tf.sqrt()` results in an `InternalError`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# enable eager execution
tf.enable_eager_execution()

> tf.pow(2,4)
'Out': <tf.Tensor: id=48, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=16>

> tf.sqrt(4)

>>> Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-21-5dc8e2f4780c>", line 1, in <module>
    tf.sqrt(4)

  File "/Users/ekababisong/anaconda3/envs/py36_dl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
     tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 365, in sqrt
         return gen_math_ops.sqrt(x, name=name)

  File "/Users/ekababisong/anaconda3/envs/py36_dl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
     tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 7795, in sqrt
        _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from

InternalError: Could not find valid device for node name: "Sqrt"
op: "Sqrt"
input: "dummy_input"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_INT32
  }
}
 [Op:Sqrt] name: Sqrt/
```

Comment: Try converting to floating point first.

Comment: @P-Gn how did you know it was floating point?  I am saying because specifiying floating point fixed my answer as well for conv1D

Comment: my input tensor is float32 and I still have the same error, solution?

Comment: @DsCpp did you try converting to int? (ie. `x = tf.cast(x, tf.int32`)  ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: @DsCpp if you are debugging `reshape()` like me, you may need to make sure the second parameter to `reshape(x, [this_param])` is a tuple of integers.  I was converting old python2 code to python3

Answer (score 25):

I got a similar error when trying to pass an image through a convolutional filter. Turns out it was solved as P-Gn said, simply by convert it to float.

```py
x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)
```

Comment: Got the same error, don't know why. Did tf.cast, no error now, don't know why. Weird error prompt for simple cast.

Comment: I guess its because the dtypes of both the operands is different. Some kind of data mismatch error while operating.

Answer (score 1):

Got a similar error when trying to find Nan Values in a dictionary, P-Gn's solution worked.

TF2.0 RC, 
Before (Internal Error : Could not find valid device for node) :

```
any(tf.math.is_nan(val) for val in dict.values())
```

After :

```
any(tf.math.is_nan(tf.cast(val, tf.float32) for val in dict.values())
```

Returns true / false

Answer (score 1):

In this case that the value is just *int* it might be a good idea just to use *numpy*.

In case you still want to use TensorFlow it can be done like this:

```
tf.math.sqrt(tf.convert_to_tensor(4, dtype='float32'))
```

or

```
tf.sqrt(tf.convert_to_tensor(4, dtype='float32'))
```

tested on **TensorFlow 2**